# How to pass filehandle as reference between modules and subs in perl

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference

I'm maintaining old Perl code and need to enable strict pragma in all modules. I have a problem in passing a file handle as a reference between modules and subs. We have a common module responsible for opening the log file which is passed as typeglob reference. In other modules, the run function first calls open_log() from the common module, then it passes this file handle to other subs.

Here I've written a simple test to simulate the situation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

$::STATUS_OK = 0;
$::STATUS_NOT_OK = 1;

sub print_header {
  our $file_handle = @_;

  print { $$file_handle } "#### HEADER ####"; # reference passing fails
}

sub print_text {
  my ($file_handle, $text)= @_;

  print_header(\$file_handle);
  print { $$file_handle } $text;
}

sub open_file_handle {
  my ($file_handle, $path, $name) = @_;

  my $filename = $path."\\".$name;
  unless ( open ($$file_handle, ">".$filename)) {
    print STDERR "Failed to open file_handle $filename for writing.\n";
    return $::STATUS_NOT_OK;
  }
  print STDERR "File $filename was opened for writing successfully.\n";
  return $::STATUS_OK;
}

my $gpath = "C:\\Temp";
my $gname = "mylogfile.log";
my $gfile_handle;

if (open_file_handle(\$gfile_handle, $gpath, $gname) == $::STATUS_OK) {
  my $text = "BIG SUCCESS!!!\n";
  print_text(\$gfile_handle, $text);
  print STDERR $text;
} else {
  print STDERR "EPIC FAIL!!!!!!!!\n";
}
```

The Main function first calls `open_file_handle` and passes a file handle reference to the `print_text` function. If I comment out the row:

```
print_header(\$file_handle);
```

Everything works fine, but I need to pass the file handle reference to other functions from the `print_text` function, and this doesn't work.

I'm a Java developer and Perl's reference handling is not familiar to me. I don't want to change the `open_log()` sub to return a file handle (now it returns only status), since I have lots of modules and hundreds of code lines to go through to make this change in all places.

How can I fix my code to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two types of filehandles in Perl. Lexical and global bareword filehandles:

```
open my $fh, '>', '/path/to/file' or die $!;
open FILEHANDLE, '>', '/path/to/file' or die $!;
```

You are dealing with the first, which is good. The second one is global and should not be used.

The file handles you have are lexical, and they are stored in a scalar variable. It's called scalar because it has a dollar sign `$`. These can be passed as arguments to subs.

```
foo($fh);
```

They can also be referenced. In that case, you get a scalar reference.

```
my $ref = \$fh;
```

Usually you reference stuff if you hand it over to a function so Perl does not make a copy of the data. Think of a reference like a pointer in C. It's only the memory location of the data (structure). The piece of data itself remains where it is.

Now, in your code you have references to these scalars. You can tell because it is dereferenced in the `print` statement by saying `$$fh`.

```
sub print_text {
  my ($file_handle, $text)= @_;

  print_header(\$file_handle);
  print { $$file_handle } $text;
}
```

So the `$file_handle` you get as a parameter (that's what the `= @_` does) is actually a reference. You do not need to reference it again when you pass it to a function.

I guess you wrote the `print_header` yourself:

```
sub print_header {
  our $file_handle = @_;

  print { $$file_handle } "#### HEADER ####"; # reference passing fails
}
```

There are a few things here:
- [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) is for globals. Do not use that. Use [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) instead.
- Put parenthesis around the parameter assignment: `my ($fh) = @_`
- Since you pass over a reference to a reference to a scalar, you need to dereference twice: `${ ${ $file_handle } }`

Of course the double-deref is weird. Get rid of it passing the variable `$file_hanlde` to `print_header` instead of a refence to it:

```
sub print_text {
  my ($file_handle, $text)= @_;

  print_header($file_handle); # <-- NO BACKSLASH HERE
  print { $$file_handle } $text;
}
```

That is all you need to to make it work.

In general, I would get rid of all the references to the `$file_handle` vars here. You don't need them. The lexical filehandle is already a [reference to an IO::Handle object](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles), but don't concern yourself with that right now, it is not important. Just remember:

- use filehandles that have a `$` up front
- pass them without references and you do not need to worry about `\` and `${}` and stuff like that

---

For more info, see [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. `our` and double-deref was just my experiments to try found out how I can make it work. Actual mistake seems to be in not putting parenthesis around the parameter assignment. I was just trying to understand how referencing works in perl. That's helped me to understand some of it.

Comment: @edufinn I'm glad it works. :) You should read the tutorial I linked. References are very powerful and an integral part of Perl. However, the scalar ones are a bit weird. Try working with a datastructure. Use Data::Dumper to look at some things and you will understand it a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are having difficulties because you added multiple extra level of references. Objects like lexical filehandles already are references.

If you have difficulties keeping track of what is a reference, you might want to use some kind of hungarian notation, like a `_ref` suffix.

In `print_text`, this would be:

```
sub print_text {
  my ($file_handle_ref, $text)= @_;

  print_header(\$file_handle_ref);
  print { $$file_handle_ref } $text;
}
```

And in `print_header`:

```
sub print_header {
  my ($file_handle_ref_ref) = @_; # don't use `our`, and assign to a lvalue list!

  print { $$$file_handle_ref_ref } "#### HEADER ####"; # double derefernence … urgh
}
```

A far superior solution is to pass the filehandle around directly, without references.

```
sub print_header {
  my ($file_handle) = @_;

  print {$file_handle} "#### HEADER ####"; # no reference, no cry
}

sub print_text {
  my ($file_handle, $text)= @_;

  print_header($file_handle);
  print {$file_handle} $text;
}
```

And in the main part:

```
my $gpath = "C:/Temp"; # forward slashes work too, as long as you are consistent
my $gname = "mylogfile.log";

if (open_file_handle(\my $gfile_handle, $gpath, $gname) == $::STATUS_OK) {
  my $text = "BIG SUCCESS!!!\n";
  print_text($gfile_handle, $text);
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reference operator is "\" (backslash)
anything includes arrays, hashes and even sub-routines can be referenced

the 5th line to count backwards

```
print_text(\$gfile_handle, $text);
```

you passed a referenced variable `\$gfile_handle` to the sub-routine `print_text`

```
sub print_text {
    my ($file_handle, $text)= @_;

    print_header(\$file_handle);
    print { $$file_handle } $text;
}
```

and in this sub-routine, `$file_handle` is already a reference
then your referenced it again and pass it to the sub-routine `print_header`

so, you can solve this problem by putting off the reference operator the 5th line to count backwards like this:
    `print_text($gfile_handle, $text);`

and try again :-)